Как сделать так, чтобы фон под меню при скролле на ios был такого же цвета как меню CSS?
Сделал панельку меню в CSS, но столкнулся с такой проблемой - если на мобильной версии попытаться проскроллить вниз, то цвет под меню будет таким же как у страницы. Но как можно сделать так, чтобы цвет был таким же как у меню?
Думал сделать прямоугольник с высотой 1000px и поместить его снизу, но вдруг есть решение получше?
P.S. на скриншоте меню по центру в момент скролла страницы, а так оно находится снизу.


body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100svh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 24px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 32px 32px 0 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
<div id="root">
  <main class="main"></main>
  <nav class="menu"></nav>
</div>





а под меню есть что-то, что бы окрашивалось? и вообще должно ли меню подниматься, если оно внизу?
